# Написать математическую формулу на PYTHON

Tags: python

Для решения задачи необходимо вставить формулу [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в код

```
from math import factorial 

def func(a,b):

    pass

    return 

n = int(input())

first = func(n, 11)

second = func(n - 11, 11)

print((first * second)/2)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести формулу в код!

Comment: а мельче формулу нельзя было разместить? А в чем именно проблема написать код? В чем именно у вас сложности? Вы же вот уже что-то написали

Comment: что-то переносить-то? Бери и элементарно переписывай, только не забывай за скобками следить.

Answer (score 2):

Этот код должен решить вашу задачу

```
import math as m

n = int(input())

C = m.factorial(n) / (m.factorial(11) * (m.factorial(abs(n-11))))

print(C)
```

Comment: Интересная формула, кстати. Ведь что делать при n < 11 в ней не указано.